# Change timeout for message review in Exchange Online?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-365

I have set up some phishing/malware mail-flow rules that will forward emails to me for review based on attachments or a list of domains. I can then choose to accept or reject the message.  It seems to work well. The problem I'm having is that this weekend, some were automatically rejected because I didn't respond in time.

How do I change this time to "auto reject"?

Comment: Which phishing/malware policies did you deploy? Malware/spam filter in EAC or others?

Comment: These are manually created mail-flow rules. I should not have used the word "policies".  Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, run this command to verify that the expiry period is 2 days:

`get-retentionpolicytag moderatedrecipients | fl`

You should see the `Agelimitforretention` listed as `02.00:00:00`, or 2 days exactly

To change it, use the following command:

`set-retentionpolicytag moderatedrecipients -agelimitforretention 05.00:00:00`

Where `05` in this example is 5 days. Vary it to suit your requirements. (Maximum 9 Days)

Re-run the first command in order to verify that the change has been made.

Comment: This is not working. I just received a message that states `requested your approval of the attached message for delivery to the following recipient. Because no moderation decision was made within 2 days, the message has been returned to the sender. `  And it was only 2 days.

I have confirmed with the command above that the `ModeratedRecipients` retention policy is still set to `10.00:00:00`.  This must be a different policy.

Comment: Hah. Per Microsoft Support: `You can increase the number of days from 2 to maximum of 9 days`.  I suppose by me setting it to 10 days it just reverted to the default.  Testing 9 days now.

Comment: @THEJOATMON Thanks for comment, I've never pushed it past 5 days but I'll update the answer with the limit.